# How will my party get through level 1 of The Sunless Citadel?

Tags: dnd-5e, tales-from-the-yawning-portal

My party of five 1st-level characters are halfway through level 1 of *The Sunless Citadel*. We finished our last session with them in area 38, undecided where to go next.  I'm worried because both of their next two choices seem deadly:

**Option 1:**

> They lock-pick their way into area 37, the *Trophy Room*, where *Calcryx* the white dragon wyrmling is. "She is hostile to those who enter the chamber", and I'm afraid a well-placed breath attack could wipe out my party (even though *Erky Timbers* is with them)

**Option 2:**

> They blunder straight into area 41, *Hall of the Goblin Chief*, where four hobgoblins (including the beefed-up boss), a twig blight and a goblin shaman will surely wipe out the party. The bad guys are worth 475 XP combined. This is getting into the "Deadly" territory according to page 82 of the DMG:  five 1st level characters would consider 5 x 75 = 375XP hard, and 5 x 100 = 500XP deadly.

What do you think? Should I warn my players that they're about to get in over their heads?  Should I

> have Calcryx roll on his back and behave like a happily-found puppy?

Comment: Option 1 is definitely a valid concern: I accidentally wiped a level 1 party that way (most of them got killed outright). When I got a party through alive they were level 2, but it might be a bit late for that in your case, so I don't have much experience to help.

Comment: Are those Hard and Deadly XP totals calculated with or without considering Erky?

Comment: Ah good point @DarthPseudonym:  Erky is like a 2nd level priest, so definitely change the calcs, make the encounter not so _Hard_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### "Deadly" is only a possibility, and this isn't even Deadly

In my experience, even "deadly" encounters aren't all that deadly, especially if the PCs hit one right off a long rest.

Moreover, these two fights are actually just Hard, not even to the minimum Deadly level yet. Deadly is 500 or more XP, Hard runs from 375 to 499. It's getting close, but still well inside Hard territory.

It's certainly possible a PC will go down for good in either of these fights, but 1st level PCs are fragile, so that's a risk in almost any fight. You're right to be concerned about the dragon-breath attack, though. That could be anywhere from painful to an instant party wipe, depending on your dice rolls.

### Hostile doesn't mean instant combat.

As the DMG says, "a hostile creature opposes the adventurers and their
goals but doesn't necessarily attack them on sight." I don't have *Tales from the Yawning Portal* in front of me, so I'm not sure whether it specifically says Calcryx attacks immediately, but even if it does, I might consider changing that. Combat is fun, but it seems like meeting your first dragon should be something a little more special and interesting than, say, meeting your first dire wolf. Giving the PCs the opportunity to talk, bribe, or otherwise make a deal with Calcryx would give them the chance to avoid that nasty fight, if they decide to go that direction.

Comment: +1 for the last part, dragons need to be memorable!

Comment: Honestly if they meet the dragon and it comes to a fight, that's a place where I might consider fudging the damage roll for the breath weapon.  If I see most of the party failing their save and the damage roll is in the 18+ range (i.e. massive damage insta-death for a lot of level 1 PCs) I might fudge it down to a 12 or so.  But really, don't fight that thing until you're second level, the difference in survivability between level 1 and level 2 is vast.  (Going from 1 to 2 increases your HP by about 70% on average, while going from 10 to 11 is a relatively tiny difference.)

Comment: There is the consideration that if a party of level 1 characters engage a dragon, maybe they deserve it ...

Comment: Right, but that's why I think it's important to *give* the party that option. If the dragon just immediately attacks, they haven't really *chosen* to engage with a dragon, they just opened an anonymous door and had a fight dropped in their laps.